# What is the difference between a dead cat and a foam screen?

Tags: microphone

What is the difference between a [dead cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Blimps) (the furry ones) and a foam screen when it comes to the result? Is one of them better than the other? Do they have different applications?

Comment: What? Is a dead cat some kind of windscreen or something?

Comment: It's the furry ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dead cat is vastly superior in cutting down on the wind noise. I've used both and it really is light years apart. If you are doing docu work outside, the dead cat is a must. A zeppelin is great, but expensive and bulky. I use a dead cat for international shooting and find it the best compromise between foam and the zep...

Answer (score 2):

The dead cat is supposed to have slightly better wind noise reduction, but the foam screens are cheaper and don't suffer from the same problems the dead cat has (dirt and objects getting stuck, it losing its fluff when wet etc) which lead to it ending up with very poor wind noise reduction.

Comment: Thanks! By losing its fluff, does this mean that it doesn't work even as good as a foam screen?

Comment: Edited to include info as requested